# All-day event reminder in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a way to change the **default** reminder of an all-day event in Outlook 2010 from 18 hours? I've noticed several old posts indicating it cannot be changed without having to use a macro, but am wondering if Microsoft updated this.

Answer (score 0):

The default reminder for all day event is still not user configurable. You need to change it each time you create an all day event with a reminder. If you would like to use a macro, [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1611-outlook-reminder-default-all-day-events-18-hours.html) may be helpful.